# concurrent requests handling in java

Tags: concurrency

in our application, if user logged in as admin he can do any operation. supposed one admin modifying a route,if second admin at the same time checked the same route and creating an airwaybill for the same route.This will be a problem. I could not find how my application is handling these concurrent requests.
(we are simply using jdbc transactions)

I am getting different answers from my team   1. web/application server handles these transactions and it will handle concurrent requests without any issues.
2. locks will be happened on rows on database and there wont be any problem for concurrent requests.

bottomline : concurrent requests should be handled in code? or we shall do any setting in web/application for concurrent requests while deploying? or by default database will handle concurrent requests by row locking mechanism?

if anyone knows where to find the solution , please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware most database engines use some kind of locking during queries, but it will differ depending on the engine. I know that InnoDB enforces transaction atomicity ([see this stack exchange thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/mysql-transaction-vs-lock)) so anything that is wrappend in a transaction wont be interfered with mid execution. However there is no guaruntee as to which request will reach the datbase first.

As for the webServer/appServer, assuming your using a threaded web server: apache tomcat, jetty etc then each request is handled as by a seperate thread so I would assume is no inherent thread saftey. In the majority of cases the database will handle your concurrency without complaining, however i would recommend including a some kind of serialisation on the application end in case you decide to change DB implementation somewhere down the road, you will also have more control over how requests are handled.

In short ..... do both.

Comment: I am using apache tomcat server and database is oracle. I will not change tomcat server / database . so can I ignore handling the concurrent transanctions  " the database will handle your concurrency without complaining" , is it ?

Comment: I would suggest putting some kind of defensive measures in place on the server for the sake of defensiveness, that way your less likely to be caught out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most databases has some kind of locking during the transactions and queries, but you should check the database references to ensure the type of locking method it uses. As for your problem with your web server, I know that tomcat handles requests concurrently and offers some kind of thread safety for it's own resources, but it offers no thread safety for your application.Thus, you should do it on your own. For the problem you mentioned above, I think when you are accessing your route, you should query it against the database whether it exists or not. Also when your other admin is modifying the route, you can use some sort of lock on the block you are doing that so that when the other admin at the same time wants to access the route that is being modified, he waits for the transaction to be completed. if you are using java for the server side, I recommend to see java synchronization methods or if another language, check locking and thread safety methods for that language.